# When I declare a function inside a class I get name error

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first code work properly but when I declare the 'toStr' function(or method) inside the class I get error. What's wrong with this code?
First Code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,hour,minute,second):
        self.hour=hour
        self.minute=minute
        self.second=second

# Return String Time Format
def toStr(self):
    return str(self.hour)+":"+str(self.minute)+":"+str(self.second)
t=Test(10,20,50)
print(toStr(t))
```

The second code with NameError:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,hour,minute,second):
        self.hour=hour
        self.minute=minute
        self.second=second

# Return String Time Format
    def toStr(self):
        return str(self.hour)+":"+str(self.minute)+":"+str(self.second)
t=Test(10,20,50)
print(toStr(t))
```

Comment: You cannot call `print(toStr(t))` if it belongs to the class

Comment: could you please be more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-> As you are working with object-oriented concepts. you should be familiar with it. whenever you create a class you have to create object of it to use its functionality

```
class MyTest: #class
    def __init__(self, hour, minute, second): #constructor
        self.hour=hour
        self.minute=minute
        self.second=second

    def toStr(self): #method
        return str(self.hour)+":"+str(self.minute)+":"+str(self.second)

obj=MyTest(4,5,5) # class object
print(obj.toStr()) # to call toStr() method you have to use it with a object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code,

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,hour,minute,second):
        self.hour=hour
        self.minute=minute
        self.second=second

# Return String Time Format
    def toStr(self):
        return str(self.hour)+":"+str(self.minute)+":"+str(self.second)

t=Test(10,20,50)
print(t.toStr())
```

here is my output,

```
10:20:50
```

You can't call the `toStr` function outside the `t` object (Test class), you need to call it using the dot operator because the `toStr` function belongs to the `Test` class now.

Comment: @mohamadbari if i helped, please mark my answer as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to either call the method on the object like:

```
print(t.toStr())
```

or

```
print(Test.toStr(t))
```